# Can you use an offset with the add instruction?

Tags: assembly, mips

I have a questions that asks whether this is valid MIPS:

add $5, $8,8($4)

I think it's not valid because you cannot have an offset in R-type instructions.  Am I correct?

Comment: You are correct. You can't use a memory operand at all.

Comment: `8($4)` is traditionally written that way with the constant outside and before the parens, with a register inside, so as to suggest this is a memory addressing mode, i.e. adding register $8's value to memory location value, that is addressed by $4's value + 8.  Such is possible in x86 but not MIPS or RISC V, where memory is accessed by special load/store instructions instead of arithmetic ones.  This restriction is one of the meanings behind *Reduced* Instruction Set Computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is nonsense.

Offsets are only meaningful in the context of an instruction that accesses memory, like `lw` or `sw`. `add` is not such an instruction.